# remove duplicate values in a tuple array in python

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, tuples

I have a party whom purchases products. Every time the customer purchases a product, a new row is generated with the same party number.

I have grouped the products on party number and I am now stuck with a column which has arrays of tuples in it

| Party Nbr | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (a, a, a, a, b, c) |
| 2 | (a, d, a, a) |
| 3 | (a, a, b, b, b) |

I cant find how I can remove all duplicates from each row of the product column.

Code for the groupby:

```
pf = prod.groupby(['Party Nbr'])['Product name'].apply(tuple).reset_index().rename(columns= {'Product name': 'Product'})

pf['Product'] = tuple(set(pf['Product']))


ValueError: Length of values (4663) does not match length of index (32539)
```

Someone able to help me?

Comment: Try converting the tuples into a set, and back into a tuple: `tuple(set(table_entry))`

Comment: When I use set() it gives the error that the Length of Values and Length of index do not match

Comment: tuple-> set -> tuple doesn't necessarily preserve order tough?

Comment: Show us your code and the full error you receive.

Comment: @ChristianSloper no, it does not. However OP does not mention order is important

Comment: @ChristianSloper true, but given we know they are "products", probably doesn't matter.  But it is definitely important to be aware of that detail.  In any case, the OP should share some of their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you are using `pandas`, I recreated your table into a dataframe, and show how you could do the transform.

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({
              "party": [1, 2, 3], 
              "product": [
                  ("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c"),
                  ("a", "d", "a", "a"),
                  ("a", "a", "b", "b", "b")]})

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   party             product
0      1  (a, a, a, a, b, c)
1      2        (a, d, a, a)
2      3     (a, a, b, b, b)

In [13]: df["product"] = df["product"].apply(set).apply(tuple)

In [14]: df
Out[17]: 
   party    product
0      1  (c, b, a)
1      2     (a, d)
2      3     (b, a)
```

**Note:** as mentioned in the comments, the order of the products is not preserved, you want to preserve the order, you can use a custom function in place of chaining `set` & `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate from a `tuple` you can use the `set` type that will automatically remove duplicates. You can do it in a simple call :

```py
In [1]: a=(1,2,2,1,1,1,1,3)

In [2]: tuple(set(a))
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3)
```